# KML Layers rendering order google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, jak

I have noticed some different behavior with the following APIS

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2062/

Sometimes the polygon layer renders ontop of the balloon layer, and sometimes the opposite.

It seems like after the map is "cached?" in the browser it will render with the polygon layer ontop. Is there anyway to prevent this? Or to have one layer always be in the background? Unfortunately I cannot map these layers in one kml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layers get rendered in the order they are received from the server (which is not necessarily the order in which they appear in the code).  You can force one to load after the other by waiting for the KmlLayer status_changed event before setting the map property of the second.

```
function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(-122.365662,37.826988);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: chicago
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/gmaptest123/kml/nst.kml'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, "status_changed", function() {
    ctaLayer2.setMap(map);
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  var ctaLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/gmaptest123/kml/HelloKml6.kml'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyTvB/1/)

Comment: Hey I apreciate your comment. However that seems to produce the same behavior. See my updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/uyTvB/2/

Comment: Don't you want the layer with the polygons on the bottom? http://jsfiddle.net/uyTvB/3/

Comment: Ah yeah. I realized what that code is doing now. I haneed to render the one I want ontop last! Thanks. http://jsfiddle.net/uyTvB/4/

Comment: Note, the real solution would be for the API to provide relative control of the [KmlLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#KmlLayerOptions) with [something like zIndex (enhancement request)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4492) as opposed to this control of the order of adding the layers.

Comment: Yes I agree. I saw an enhancement request to google from 2010 but nothing has come of it yet. I wish I had more exp so I could upvote all your comments....:( You go out of your way to be very helpful

Comment: Hi is it possible to map a set of client side markers ontop of one KML but behind another?

Comment: [Everything is possible, you just have to code it.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/408519/marcelo).  You need to provide more information. If the markers are in a separate KML file, you can control the layering order by the order they are rendered on the map as indicated in my answer, it applies to however many layers you want to render, just increases the time to display the map.

Comment: There are 3 kml files and then a set of 'google.maps.Circle' markers. I need to render them in order kml, circles, kml, kml. Can I enter in some type of wait period?

Comment: Circles will always be on top of KML.  Make a KML file to contain the Circles also.  I would suggest chaining them, on the status_changed event of the first, load the second, on the status_changed event of the second load the third, etc.

Comment: I was under the impression that there was no marker for circle in KML or am I incorrect in this assumption? I am using client side for circles because I thought it was not available in the kml

Comment: No, you are correct. You need to make circular polygons. [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_update.html?lat=37.430783&lng=-122.085125&zoom=10&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/dynamicmarkerkml.php)

Comment: hmm. The circles radius is a dynamic value based on data coming from a report. I think processing lat/long points to draw that circle with a specific radius may take awhile to process.

Comment: You could confirm, but if the circles need to be in a particular place in the layering, that isn't the top, you might need to use other options (not layers or KML; or use a third party KML parser to render the KML as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects) for the things that need to be above them.

Comment: Hmm. KML layers are needed in this application because of the size of data. Im just afraid of relying anymore on client side than I need to. If there were some type of marker in KML that would convey volume that would be great. Unfortunately that doesn't seem available.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2065/)**

Add these two parameters to your markers layer:

```
pane: "floatPane",
preserveViewport: true
```

So it looks like this:

```
var ctaLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/gmaptest123/kml/HelloKml6.kml',
    pane: "floatPane",
    preserveViewport: true
});
```

The default is, I believe, mapPane, which has a lower z-index than floatPane.

Comment: Thank you, on initial testing that seemed to make the markers render in front. Ill need to look at the API to understand whats going on. Appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting method in [this link](https://gist.github.com/jkeefe/1170104). Here is the actual ordering code:

```
// BEGIN SEQUENTIAL KML LOADING CODE
// This ensures the layers are drawn in order: cone, warnings, track

// Draw coneLayer
coneLayer.setMap(map);

// Listen for when coneLayer is drawn
var listener1 = google.maps.event.addListener(coneLayer, 'metadata_changed', function() {
  // When it's drawn (metadata changed), clear listener, draw warningsLayer ...
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(coneLayer, 'metadata_changed');
  warningsLayer.setMap(map);

  // .. and listen for when warningsLayer is drawn
  var listener2 = google.maps.event.addListener(warningsLayer, 'metadata_changed', function() {
    // When it's drawn, clear listener, draw trackLayer ...
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(warningsLayer, 'metadata_changed');
    trackLayer.setMap(map);

    // ... and listen for when trackLayer is drawn
    var listener3 = google.maps.event.addListener(trackLayer, 'metadata_changed', function() {
      // When it's drawn, clear listener and blank out the map-loading sign
      google.maps.event.clearListeners(trackLayer, 'metadata_changed');
      $('#loadingIndicator').html("");

    });

  });

});

// END SEQUENTIAL KML LOADING CODE
```