# How to bring Google Map marker in front of D3 circles

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, d3.js

I am working on a little project that has a lot of D3 shapes, and a few google map markers. The problem is that : most of the markers appear behind the D3 circles. I have tried changing the z-index of both the circles, and the markers, by making the z-index of d3 very small, and the markers very big, and that did not help either.

Any help will be really appreciated. I have tried a wide range of z-index values and none seems to work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Basic example would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a snapshot: http://i.imgur.com/6aBsyIL.jpg . At this point, I have set z-index of d3 to be 0, and of google maps marker to be of 1000 but, the markers still show up behind. It is probably because D3 is an overlay on top of google map, and the markers probably live on the map. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482115/with-javascript-can-i-change-the-z-index-layer-of-an-svg-g-element/482147#482147

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337507/kml-layers-rendering-order-google-maps) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment everybody. I ended up using D3 instead of google map markers. the performance is slightly hindered, but adding and removing landmarks is much easier now. Thanks a lot.